# $p_n+2<3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot p_{n-1}$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can we show that $p_n+2<3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot p_{n-1}$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime for $n\ge 4$? It seems intuitive but I would not even know where to begin to try to prove this.

Comment: "It seems intuitive" Care to expand?

Comment: Do you mean something like $p_n+2<\prod _{k=2}^{n-1} p_2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $3*5*\cdots*p_{n-1}-4$ is odd and prime to each of $3$, $5,\dots p_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Winther Because $p_j\mid 3\cdot 5\cdots p_{n-1}-4\implies j\ge n$, so $3\cdot 5\cdots p_{n-1}-4\ge p_n>p_n-2$.

Comment: @user236182 You also need to use that it's strictly greater than $1$: being coprime to the first $n-1$ primes is not quite a sufficient condition to be prime :).

Comment: @Winther $p_n$ is the $n$'th prime in the list of prime numbers.

Comment: @ErickWong I never said that $3\cdot 5\cdots p_{n-1}-4$ is prime, only that it's divisible by the $j$'th prime, where $j\ge n$, and it's clear that since $n\ge 4$, we have $3\cdot 5\cdots p_{n-1}-4\ge 11$.

Comment: @Winther Note that $3\cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdots p_{n-1}$ *must* have a prime divisor. Can that divisor be less than $p_n$? Also, this is just the proof of Euclid's theorem.

Comment: @user236182 Sorry, my phrasing was poor.  I should have said that $3\cdot 5\cdots p_{n-1}-4 > 1$ is a small but critical observation to ensure there is at least one prime satisfying the if clause.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for clearing up my confusion. I was way off in my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bertrand's postulate:
Let $k>3$. Then there is a prime number $p$ such that $k<p<2k-2$.

From this we can see that $p_n<2p_{n-1}-2$ (noting that $p_n \geq 7$ so we can apply the postulate). In particular, this means that $p_n+2<2p_{n-1}<3p_{n-1}$ which is then obviously less than the expression you have on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

$p_{n-1}\ge 5$ and by [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) $p_n<2p_{n-1}$, so

$$p_n+2<2p_{n-1}+2<2p_{n-1}+p_{n-1}=3p_{n-1}\le 3\cdot 5\cdots p_{n-1}$$